# How to disable inserting "&nbsp;" with AltGr+Spacebar on Linux Mint 19?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

Sometimes I accidentally type Spacebar with AltGr key which inserts the `&nbsp;` (the non-breaking space). I want to change this behaviour so this combination will insert space symbol or nothing at all. I've tried using this command: `setxkbmap -option "nbsp:none"`. Problem is it works only in the current session. Adding this line to the `.profile` file doesn't make the change persistent. I'm using Linux Mint 19 with Cinnamon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, nevermind I found a solution:

Open the *System Settings* then go to the *Keyboard Settings*. Click the *Layouts* tab, and then the *Options...* button in the right bottom corner. You should see the list of *Keyboard Layout Options*. You can change the behaviour of your keyboard here. On the bottom of the list, you can see *Using space key to input non-breaking space*, click to open the drop-down menu. For me, *Usual space at any level* works just fine, but you can experiment if you wish.